# Selenium web driver : Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: ce6fd}

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, intellij-idea

while I am running a selenium webdriver script I got an error named

```
"org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output".
```

platform used :

1. Firefox - 44.0.2
2. selenium web driver - 2.48.2
3. language - java

Also I tried many suggestion by google with different version of firefox and selenium but still I am facing this issue. Please help me out to overcome with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Selenium 3.0.1 with latest Firefox. Don't forget to [download the gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set the System variable to it's path:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks @Moshisho your solution works for me but I can able to access normal url through my script like google and other web without security certification. But when I am trying to access my project web url which requires manually adding of certification exception then my script is stopping at step of  adding certification exception manually and I am getting error like this "Error loading page (WARNING: The server did not provide any s tacktrace information)(..)"

Comment: Please suggest me solution

Comment: That requires a new question;) with more details... I don't know how your project accepts certificates, maybe you can work around that with a REST call or something like that...

Comment: Ok I will create new question thanks for your solution